# Key window doesn't rotate

Tags: iphone, objective-c, rotation, orientation, uitableview

I have a UIViewTable with navigation bar. When I read data I display UIViewController with ActivityIndicator on top of the table. The problem is when I rotate device this top view is not rotating, I don't know why? :(
This is how I add top view with ActivityIndicator:

```
UIView *view = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
[view addSubview:viewWithLoader.view];
```

This is how I remove it:

```
[viewWithLoader.view removeFromSuperview];
```

This is method from top view (with ActivityIndicator):

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)interfaceOrientation 
{
    return YES;
}
```

Comment: Do you have other subviews that Do rotate?

Comment: Yes all works fine. This one also works fine before I add it as 'keyWindow'. But I have to do that because if I say just [self.view addsubview:viewWithLoader]... then my it is not over the navigation bar.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

after you call  [self.window makeKeyAndVisible]; on your App delegate, the views that get the rotation notification, animation, etc, etc. are the subviews of that initial view.

It happen to me that I had a top bar that replaced the status bar. so I thought it will be a good idea to actually add it as a sub view of the key window. But that being the case resulted in the outcome you are experiencing.

You have 2 options

1. whoever owns that topview should take care of rotating it or remove/add it when a rotation occurs so it has the right orientation.
2. make that topview a subview of one of the views that ARE autorotating.

Both are really easy to implement but I found no. 2 is more visually attractive for the user.

Comment: I navigate to the view with button that invoke this view with loader. That view rotation is fine. I rotate it from portrait to landscape and push the button the top view orientation is not changed:
This button: ... [self.view addSubView:viewWithLoader];

Comment: Try removing and adding the topView when it is rotated.  Remove the view with loader when willRotate... is called on the current view controller and add it when didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation: is called.

Answer (score 0):

I found solution :) I add this top view (with loader) as 'modal view' and rotation works fine in all views :)

```
...
[self presentModalViewController:ldr animated:YES];
...
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```